# Which tools are available to call somatic mutations on non-coding regions from whole genome sequencing data?

Tags: wgs, mutations, somatic, non-coding

I have a set of whole genome sequencing samples, some of which have matched normal while some not. I want to call somatic mutations on non-coding regions.

I was looking for GATK best practices (like [this](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/best-practices/mutect2.php)) but it seems it is not yet ready for production. Which alternative tools do you suggest?

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/somatic-tumor-only-variant-calling

Comment: @Bioathlete thanks, I actually didn't find that question before. However, I found that question too specific on tumor-only samples. I also have normals so maybe there are better tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those will have to be treated as separate analysis.  You can use Mutect or VarScan for the matched samples and the tools listed in the [other question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/somatic-tumor-only-variant-calling) for the unmatched samples however that means that you won't be able to compare the results easily.  If the inter-sample comparison is important you will have to run all samples as unmatched.  Personally I have used LoFreq for somatic variant detection with some success.  It is very sensitive so the false positive rate can be high depending on how noisy your data is.